# ubuntu 15.04 vsphere 5.5 pyvmomi ssl error rejected self signed ssl

Tags: maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

ubuntu 15.04 vsphere 5.5 pyvmomi ssl error rejected self signed ssl

logs report that api cannot authenticate the ssl. It then closes connection the system not powering on using pyvmomi scripts into vcenter 5.5

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if this question had a copy of the actual error log seen and what logfile the error is presented in. I'm guess this is an error seen on the MAAS server as Landscape autopilot doesn't directly talk to vsphere; MAAS does.  It would be helpful if you tried powering the nodes in MAAS via the UI http:///#/nodes to confirm that it succeeds.

Also, I have see MAAS' inability to power nodes through vsphere in a case where the vsphere password has non-printable characters potentially due to some urlencoding magic that MAAS does in order to execute power changes through the vsphere API. [Here is the bug for more details](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1507757). In that bug, I found changing my password worked around the issue and MAAS was able to power nodes through pyvmomi.

Hope that helps.